# Azure Website doesn't connect to linked MySQL DB after migrating from Free to Pay-As-You-Go

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service, cleardb

I am having issues connecting to the MySQL Db connected to my Azure website. I recently moved from `free` to `pay as you go`.

I believe the DB is hosted by clearDB so I do not understand why it's not connected. When I click on the DB from the management portal on azure I get the error:

> The management site for the database isn't available right now. Please try again later.

Please help me figure this out.